# Filtrar lista por array de palavras-chaves

Tags: jquery, array, substring, contains

A ideia é fazer um filtro.

Tenho um campo de texto que o usuário digita o que quer filtrar, então armazeno as palavras digitadas em um array. Ex.: O usuário digitou no campo "config empresa", o array fica assim:

```
arrayBusca = ['config', 'empresa']
```

Preciso filtrar a lista para que exiba apenas itens que contém **OS DOIS** itens do array. Se o usuário digitar "config empresa" deve exibir o registro "Configuração da empresa" e esconder os outros como "Empresas" ou "Configurações gerais".

Até agora fiz isso, mas não funciona pois ele exibe outros registros que contém só a palavra "Config" e outros que só contém "empresa"

```
var arrayBusca = busca.split(" ");

for(x in searchArray){
    menusFiltrados = $('.texto:contains(\'' + arrayBusca[x].trim() + '\')')
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode "concatenar" vários "contains".
Exemplo: `$('.texto:contains("config"):contains("empresa")')`

Você pode fazer um loop que vai adicionando os contains, fiz um só pra exemplificar, você pode melhorar.

```
var arrayBusca = ["config", "empresa"];
var stringBusca = '';

arrayBusca.forEach((item) => stringBusca = stringBusca.concat(`:contains("${item}")`));

console.log(stringBusca); // output: :contains("config"):contains("empresa")
```

Tirei a resposta de uma pergunta do SO em inglês, não posso só comentar pela pouca reputação. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416803/jquery-contains-selector-to-search-for-multiple-strings

Comment: Muito bom! Era isso que precisava, refiz a pergunta no SO inglês caso queira dar uma olhada!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67403462/how-to-filter-a-list-using-an-array-of-keywords/67403493?noredirect=1#comment119142363_67403493